# I am calling the Magento getFormKey() method and it is returning nothing

Tags: magento, methods, singleton, magento2

I am calling the Magento getFormKey() method but the code is not returning anything. The html that is below the method is also not loading. I am calling the method using the below:

```
$formKey = new Magento\Backend\Block\Admin\Formkey();
echo $formKey->getFormKey();
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this post help? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43962/what-is-getblockhtmlformkey

Comment: Those methods don't work. I ended up using $_SESSION['default']['_form_key'] Do you know how I could override the price via add to cart url?